# TCL Regex ignore/parse leading asterisks in string

Tags: regex, tcl

I am attempting to write an expect which looks for a string like this:

```
*** error doing something
```

The tcl code I am currently using looks like:

```
expect {
    -re "*** error doing something\[\r\n\]" {
        puts $log "$expect_out(buffer)"
        return 1
    }
}
```

But the string is not matching. I assume it is down to the * special character. I am not in a position to change the error output, so I must change the regex parsing to either ignore the "***" or parse it correctly.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

`*` are quantifiers in regular expressions, and thus you need to escape them if you want them to mean actual asterisks. And you may want to use braces to avoid extra escapes:

```
expect {
    -re {\*\*\* error doing something\[\r\n\]} {
        puts $log "$expect_out(buffer)"
        return 1
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: I'm not familiar with expect